# looping through an array in java

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that searches through an array to match a `String`. I currently have it set so that when a there is no match the following is printed: `No record has been found`. My problem is that it prints that text in every iteration. How can i change it so it prints it only once? heres my code:

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    Employee[] filteredEmployees = new Employee[list.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (Employee list1 : list) {
        if (list1.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            System.out.println("Found id number: " + search);
            filteredEmployees[index++] = list1;
            String filtered = Arrays.toString(filteredEmployees).replace("[","")
                    .replace("]","").replace("null", "").replace(",", "");
            System.out.println(filtered);
        } else if (!(list[index].getIdNumber().equals(search))) {
            System.out.println("No record has been found for the id number: " + search);
        }
    }  
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(filteredEmployees, 0,index);
}
```

Desired output:

```
Searching for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
```

Current output:

```
Searching for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
No record has been found for the id number: P102432
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: so... `break` the loop?

Comment: @KoosGadellaa i tried using break but then the first bit of my code didnt work.

Comment: add a boolean value to check if it was found or not and print the appropriate message according to it, check answer. it should work.

Comment: how about use a boolean to store whether any record found and print if no record found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem, while looking for the employ if i found thim i exit the loop and do nothing, but if i can't find him and i got out of the loop i will print the message.

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search){
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    Employee[] filteredEmployees = new Employee[list.length];
    boolean resultFound = false;
    int index = 0;
    for (Employee list1 : list) {
        if (list1.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            System.out.println("Found id number: " + search);
            filteredEmployees[index++] = list1;
            String filtered = Arrays.toString(filteredEmployees).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("null", "").replace(",", "");
            System.out.println(filtered);
            resultFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!resultFound){
          System.out.println("No record has been found for the id number: " + search);
    }

     return Arrays.copyOfRange(filteredEmployees, 0,index);
}
```

Comment: i still get a print `No record has been found for the id number` in the first part of the program. it iterates through the array and prints it until the string is found. how can i get rid of that?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis i meant boolean in c# it's bool.

Comment: @Deescomaster do you still get this message multiple times?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver after i removed the `!` in `if(!resultFound)` the program worked

Comment: @Deescomaster if you removed the '!' it not suppose to work.

Answer (score 3):

The short and direct answer:

Because your print statement is contained in your loop, it will print out however many times your loop iterates.  Creating a boolean to facilitate whether or not the value has been found (and then `break`ing out of the loop) will suffice to have the message print out; the concept of this has been pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280201/1079354).

However, with Java 8, there are several advantages you can get with a rewrite:

- You can `filter` elements out based on a condition.
- You can collect elements to a proper collection, such as `List<Employee>` (which you could turn back into an array if you really wanted to).
- The code is a lot cleaner and a lot more expressive; it's clear from the lambdas below that you're filtering.

Here is that code rewritten for use with Java 8.

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);

    final List<Employee> filteredEmployees = Arrays.stream(list)
                                                   .filter(e -> e.getIdNumber().equals(search))
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if(filteredEmployees.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No record has been found for the id number: " + search);
    }

    return filteredEmployees.toArray(new Employee[0]);
}
```

I will say that it doesn't make sense to have more than one Employee record to have the same ID, but this is something I leave to your discretion.

Answer (score -1):

Added a bool to check if found/not.

```
public static Employee[] searchWithId(Employee[] list, String search){
    System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
    Employee[] filteredEmployees = new Employee[list.length];
    boolean recordExist = false;
    int index = 0;
    for (Employee list1 : list) {
        if (list1.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
            System.out.println("Found id number: " + search);
            recordExist = true;
            filteredEmployees[index++] = list1;
            String filtered = Arrays.toString(filteredEmployees).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("null", "").replace(",", "");
            System.out.println(filtered);
        }
    }
     if (!recordExist)
       System.out.println("No record has been found for the id number: " + search);
     return Arrays.copyOfRange(filteredEmployees, 0,index);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
This is not a good way to write java code in arrays instead use Collections but for this use case

public static Employee[] searchWithIdNew(Employee[] list, String search){
        System.out.println("Searching for the id number: " + search);
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[list.length];
        int index=0;
        boolean found = false;
        for(int j=0;j<list.length;j++) {
            Employee emp = list[j];
            if(emp.getIdNumber().equals(search)) {
                System.out.println("Found id : "+ search+" at index :"+j);
                emps[index++] = emp;
                found=true;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            System.out.println("No record has been found for the id number: " + search);
        }
        return emps;
    }
```